# Values not stored in Tkinter Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, variable-assignment, tkinter-entry

In my code, I have tried to get the user input through text fields, store them in variables and finally print them in a tabular form.
The problem I am facing is that none of the values I enter through the text fields get displayed; when I try printing the variables, they come up empty.
Here's part of my code:

```
# SPASC

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tktrv

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SPASC")
root.geometry("410x400")
lb1 = Label(root, text="SPASC \n Welcomes You !!!", fg="red", bg="sky blue"
        , font=('Arial Black', 20), width=22, anchor=CENTER)
lb2 = Label(root, text="What would you like to compare?",
        font=('Arial', 18), anchor=CENTER)
space1 = Label(root, text="\n\n")
lb1.grid(row=0)
lb2.grid(row=5)
space1.grid(row=1)
hpw, mil = StringVar(), StringVar()

def bt_cars():
   w1 = Toplevel()
   w1.title("Choose Features")
   w1.geometry("430x200")

   lb3 = Label(w1, text="Choose features for comparison", bg="yellow"
            , font=('Arial Black', 18), width=25)
   lb4 = Label(w1, text=" ", anchor=CENTER)
   fr1 = LabelFrame(w1, width=20, padx=100)
   hpw_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Horsepower", variable=hpw, anchor='w', onvalue="Horsepower", offvalue="")
   hpw_cb.grid()
   hpw_cb.deselect()
   mil_cb = Checkbutton(fr1, text="Mileage", variable=mil, anchor='w', onvalue="Mileage", offvalue="")
   mil_cb.grid()
   mil_cb.deselect()
   var_stor = [hpw, mil]
   print(hpw)
   print(mil)
   var_fill = []
   for itr1 in var_stor:
       if itr1 != "":
           var_fill.append(itr1)
   print(var_fill)
   def car_1():
       name1 = StringVar()
       c1 = Toplevel()
       c1.title("Car 1")
       c1.geometry("430x200")
       car1_lb1 = Label(c1, text="Car Name:")
       name1_ifl = Entry(c1)
       name1 = name1_ifl.get()

       elm_var_fill = len(var_fill)
       ct1 = 0
       car1_val = []
       for itr2 in var_fill:
           if ct1 == elm_var_fill:
              break
           lb5 = Label(c1, text=itr2.get())
           #Creating text field
           ftr1_ifl = Entry(c1)
           car1_ftr = ftr1_ifl.get()
           car1_val.append(car1_ftr)
           car1_ftr = None
           lb5.grid(row=ct1 + 2, column=1)
           ftr1_ifl.grid(row=ct1 + 2, column=2)
           ct1 += 1
       print(car1_val)

       def display():
           dp = Toplevel()
           dp.title("Results")
           dp.geometry("500x200")
           car1_pt = 0
           car2_pt = 0
           car_tree = tktrv.Treeview(dp)
           car_tree["columns"] = ("car1col")
           car_tree.column("#0", width=120, minwidth=30)
           car_tree.column("car1col", width=120, minwidth=30)
           car_tree.heading("#0", text="Features" )
           car_tree.heading("car1col", text=str(name1))
           car_tree.pack()
           c1.withdraw()
           print(var_fill)
      done1_bt = Button(c1, text="Continue", command=display)
      name1_ifl.grid(row=0, column=2)
      car1_lb1.grid(row=0, column=1)
      done1_bt.grid(row=5,column=1)
      w1.withdraw()

   done_bt = Button(w1, text="Done", command=car_1)
   done_bt.grid(row=3, column=1)
   lb3.grid(row=0, column=1)
   lb4.grid(row=1, column=1)
   fr1.grid(row=2, column=1)
   root.withdraw()

bt1 = Button(root, text="CARS", width=5, font=('Calibri', 15), command=bt_cars)
bt1.grid(row=7)
space2 = Label(root, text="\n\n")
space2.grid(row=6)
root.mainloop()
```

I am facing trouble with the variables named: hpw, mil, name1.
Any help would be welcome.

*NOTE:- Please excuse the amount of code; I wanted others to replicate the error and see it for themselves*

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code and please give the part where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the variables `hpw` and `mil`, these variables are empty strings that's why you are not getting any value from those checkboxes. To get values from the checkboxes replace these lines of code:

```
var_stor = [hpw, mil]
```

with

```
var_stor = [hpw_cb.cget('onvalue'), mil_cb.cget('onvalue')]
```

since you want the `onvalue` then you must use `cget()` method to access those values.

also, replace

```
lb5 = Label(c1, text=itr2.get())
```

with

```
lb5 = Label(c1, text=itr2)
```

because now you have required values (not objects) in a list, so just need to access those values.

For the variable `name1` you can use @BokiX's method.

Comment: Thanks! hpw and mil values are now getting stored

Comment: I have a doubt; if the checkbox is not selected the offvalue will be the checkbox's value. How to get that value, because in the end, I just want to know if the checkbox will have (eg. "a_string" or "" as value)

Comment: Your situation is little complex, it is best practice to define a separate function that will get checkbox values and put them in the list or whatever your want to do. I was just answering your question because you were not able to retrieve values.

Comment: Will keep in mind that, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `get()` wrong. You cannot use `get()` right after `Entry()` because as soon as entry is created it's getting the input before the user can even input something.

Use this code:

```
def get_input(text):
  print(text)

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
b = Button(root, text="Print input", command=lambda: get_input(e.get()))
b.pack()
```

Now `get()` method will not be executed before you click the button.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, but when I now use the same logic and try to print the name variable after I have stored the values, it just displays an empty line. When I append the values(of hpw and mil) to a list and then print the list, output is coming as :  `[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x033F29A0>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x033F2A00>]` What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you write something into that `Entry` and then click the button?

Comment: This is the name text field part I had edited like you suggested: `name1_ifl = Entry(c1)
        name1_ifl.grid(row=0, column=2)
        name1 = name1_ifl.get()
        print(name1)`    Please excuse the formatting of the code lines

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You need to add a button and a function where you get the entry text.

Comment: Actually I just want the text to be displayed in the heading of a table. So I'm storing it in a variable for later use. Isn't there any way to do that without using a button?

Comment: No, use the button to create the global variable with stored information.